# Count measure with filters not grouping properly

Tags: powerbi, dax

Background: Here is the data I am using for the Power BI visualization. You may also be able to view this link and download the excel file from replit. https://replit.com/join/tzsvuaqktb-iamyolanda
[image]
I am attempting to analyze metrics by date. In this case, the sum of the fruits.

Normally I can use a measure and group it by categories in a visualization. For example, you can have a measure `= count([column A])`  that you group by fruit type.

```
Fruit  | count fruits eaten
———————————————-
Banana | 10
Apple  | 5
Peach  | 21
Total  | 36
```

Now my problem is that when I apply filters, it no longer works…

If I filter my measure like this  `=CALCULATE(SUM(["Number of Fruits"]), ["Date Eaten"]=DATE(2022,11,20)`

Then the table results like this

```
Fruit  | count fruits eaten
———————————————-
Banana | 4
Apple  | 4
Peach  | 4
Total  | 4
```

Where 4 is the sum of everything, instead of what was expected [image]

How do I filter my measure and still get it to group properly???

What I tried:
`CALCULATE(COUNT("Number of Fruits]), [Date Eaten]=DATE(2022,11,20))`

But this measure will not group in my table visualization.

Comment: Where's your sample data?

Comment: Why are you trying to add filters to your measure?

Comment: how do you get `a_date` / `var_date` ?

Comment: I was actually hoping to compare the sum between two months, November and December. Ill add those in the description.

Comment: When you want to answer a question, then, please, refer to a person like this @Mik. This will let SO understand whom you are answering to an a person will get a notification.